I want to encrypt and decrypt AES-GCM in C# language - but I am unable to decrypt
Please help me. I want to encrypt using AES-GCM algorithm in C# code.
Here is my code - however, it can not decrypt. I want to keep the decryption code intact.
How to solve this problem? Please help me.
// Encryption code.
private static byte[] salt = new byte[16]; // Fix 1: consider salt
private static byte[] iv = new byte[12];
private const int iterations = 100000; // Fix 2: apply the same iteration count 

public string Encrypt(string key, string data)
{
     byte[] tag = new byte[16];

     using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
     {
         rng.GetBytes(salt);
         rng.GetBytes(iv);
     }

     byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
     byte[] privateKey = DeriveKey(key);

     using (AesGcm aes = new AesGcm(privateKey, tag.Length))
     {
         byte[] encrypted = new byte[dataBytes.Length];
         aes.Encrypt(iv, dataBytes, encrypted, tag);

         byte[] combinedBuffer = new byte[salt.Length + iv.Length + encrypted.Length];
         Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, combinedBuffer, 0, salt.Length); // Fix 1: consider salt
         Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, combinedBuffer, salt.Length, iv.Length);
         Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypted, 0, combinedBuffer, salt.Length + iv.Length, encrypted.Length);

         string base64Buff = BuffToBase64(combinedBuffer);
         return base64Buff;
     }
}

public static byte[] DeriveKey(string password)
{
     byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

     using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, iterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
     {
         byte[] key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32); // Fix 3: use the same key size (256 bits)
         return key;
     }
}

public static string BuffToBase64(byte[] buff)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
}

public static byte[] Base64ToBuff(string b64)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
}
 
// Decryption code
 
public string Decrypt(string password, string encryptedString)
{
    Span<byte> encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString).AsSpan();
    Span<byte> salt = encryptedData[..16]; 
    Span<byte> nonce = encryptedData[16..(16 + 12)];
    Span<byte> data = encryptedData[(16 + 12)..^16];
    Span<byte> tag = encryptedData[^16..];

    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), salt.ToArray(), 100000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    using AesGcm aes = new(pbkdf2.GetBytes(32), tag.Length); 

    Span<byte> result = new byte[data.Length];
    aes.Decrypt(nonce, data, tag, result);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
}

// Run the program.
var r = new AesGcmEncryption().Encrypt("my passphrase", "abcd");
var r2 = new AesGcmEncryption().Decrypt("my passphrase", r);

Console.WriteLine(r);
Console.WriteLine(r2);

Error:

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

I tried changing all the cases, by changing the code, and searched but no one wrote similar code.

You need to append the authentication tag to the combinedBuffer array, as it essential for the decryption.
byte[] combinedBuffer = new byte[salt.Length + iv.Length + encrypted.Length + tag.Length];

    // ..

Buffer.BlockCopy(tag, 0, combinedBuffer, salt.Length + iv.Length + encrypted.Length, tag.Length);


Thanks, it worked pretty well. However I still need to consider optimizations that require real-time processing and less RAM and CPU.

Is there any reason you haven't marked my answer as the solution then?
